# Can a single docker host be managed by multiple docker-machine instances?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Using docker-machine on my system (S1), i created a docker host on AWS using amazon-ec2 driver. I have another system (S2) on which i installed docker-machine. Used generic driver and pointed docker-machine to manage the docker host on AWS. From this point onwards, i am unable to access the docker host from S1. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

[Not natively](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1328), although it [may do in the future](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2516).

There is [third party tool called `machine-share`](https://github.com/bhurlow/machine-share) to help you import and export `docker-machine` configs from one host to another without having to edit the JSON configuration.